# Etcd watch different clients

Tags: go, etcd, etcd3

I struggle with getting `etcd` `watch` working with combination of clients.

What works: I do `Watch`in `golang` client and I do `put` also there. Then watch register change. If I use `etcdctl` in same way i.e. watch/listen both in command line it also work.

What doesnt work: I publish from command line and watch in go or vice versa.

- watch commandline, put golang: doesnt work
- watch commandline, put commandline: works
- watch golang, put commandline: doesnt work
- watch golang, put golang: works

*By "doesnt work" I mean watcher is not triggered.*

Go code I am playing with (you can run like `go run main.go (true|false) (true|false))`:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3"
    "context"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    listen := os.Args[1]
    submit := os.Args[2]
    cfg := clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints: []string{"http://10.0.75.1:2379"},
    }
    c,_ := clientv3.New(cfg)
    if listen == "true" {
        fmt.Println("listening: on")
        ch := c.Watch(context.Background(), "/foo")
        go func() {
            for s := range ch {
                fmt.Println("change: ", string(s.Events[0].Kv.Value))
            }
        }()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("listening: off")
    }
    if submit == "true" {
        fmt.Println("submiting: on")
        go func() {
            for {
                c.Put(context.Background(), "/foo", time.Now().String())
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            }
        }()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("submiting: off")
    }
    println("waiting 1h")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Hour)
}
```

`etcdctl` commands I am using to publish/watch:

update:

```
no_proxy=10.0.75.1 ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl.exe --endpoints=http://10.0.75.1:2379 put /foo "$(date)"
```

watch:

```
no_proxy=10.0.75.1 ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl.exe --endpoints=http://10.0.75.1:2379 watch /foo
```